# Transcribing Weidelbach entry from 1735

Tags: palaeography, church-records, kurrent, german, 1730s

I have another entry that's quite difficult to read, and for which I could use some help with transcription.

[image]

So far, I have:

```
Catharina Elisabetha. Joh. [?] Schwei- 
tzers und Anna Elisabetha [?]in töchter-
[lein?] ist gebohren d. 14 [Decembris?] nachmittag
[?] [?] getauft [?] Tauff-
[pathin?] war Catharina Elisabeth Valentin
[?] [?] seniorus ehl. Tochter
```

Comment: Have you tried inverting black and white, and/or fiddling with the contrast and/or brightness? Sometimes that helps.